# Does non-monotonicity imply non-satiation always? Why or why not?

Tags: microeconomics, preferences

I understand that monotonic preferences imply non-satiation. But I am not sure 100% if non-monotonic functions always have satiation. An intuitive and mathematical explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: Defining the exact type of monotonicity and satiation you mean may be helpful.

Comment: Are you asking about local satiation or global satiation? Are you asking about strongly monotonic or weakly monotonic functions and their complements?

Comment: I am asking about local-satiation and strongly monotonic functions.

Comment: Then my answer does not answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the function. A non-monotonic function with satiation:
$$
U(x_1,x_2) = 0.
$$
A non-monotonic function without (global) satiation:
$$
U(x_1,x_2) = \left \lfloor{x_1}\right \rfloor  + \left \lfloor{x_2}\right \rfloor .
$$

Comment: Does non-satiation imply monotonicity always?

Comment: I wouldn't have asked these questions had I not first tried myself. You may be experienced in this field, but I am a novice. So, if you don't want to answer that fine, but I would politely remind you not to impede others from asking pertinent questions.

Comment: @FrodoBaggins What exactly have you tried? Could you edit some of your efforts into your questions? Into this one and also any other questions you may want to ask. It would help us understand better where you get stuck. If it is the mathematical notation that you find difficult I recommend reading a math textbook on analysis.

Comment: You have already asked six questions in four days. I think you may be better served by thinking more about them. As it says in the [faq](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions): "The purpose of this site is not to provide complete answer keys to homework questions"

Comment: I haven't asked homework questions, but merely conceptual questions. Plus, there is no limit on the number of questions anyone can ask in the forum.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So are you going to edit in your attempts into the questions? You wrote that you tried to solve these before asking.

Comment: Actually I figured the answer, so I am not going to post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A non-monotonic function with local non-satiation:
$$u(x, y) = x - y$$